# db_query returns one row when it shouldn't

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to check if a search query is a zip code in drupal 7

```
  $input = filter_var(urldecode(((isset($vars["view"]->exposed_input))? $vars["view"]->exposed_input["distance"]["postal_code"] : $vars["view"]->exposed_raw_input["distance"]["postal_code"])), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if($result = db_query("SELECT zip, city, state, country FROM zipcodes WHERE zip = :zip", array(":zip" => $input))) {
    if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
         //get city state and country
    } else {
         //input is not a zip code
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I set the input to a non zip code it still returns one row with the zip field set to whatever the input is and city state and country to nothing

I could just check if city state and country are nothing but I would rather have it work correctly

does anyone know why it returns one row when there isn't one in the database?

Answer (score -1):

This happens because drupal creates a new row in the database with the input zip code set before I check the row count.